# How can I keep the painting texture and texture image mixed together?

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, image, texture-painting

I'm a beginner.  I was curious how do I get both texture mixes?  For example, first texture, I paint color, second texture that's is fabrics or metal or whatever, have to blend. I cannot get both two textures to Principal Bsdf. Make sure you add a picture/gif explanation to help me better understand and show how you make it so I can comprehend how to make it myself.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mix the 2 *Principled BSDF* with the 2 different textures into a *Shader > Mix Shader*, with a b&w image as factor:

[image]

If you need to mix 2 different *Image Textures*, do it through a *Color > Mix RGB* and again, use a b&w image as factor:

[image]